# Open many "Form2" in one command

Tags: vb.net

I'm make new vb.net application that open many "form2" form "form1" with button

my code :

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For i As Integer = 1 To 5
            Form2.Show()
        Next
 End Sub
```

but this code show only 1 "form2", how can i Fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

By using the class name you are referring to the default instance and there is only ever one default instance at a time.  If you want multiple instances simultaneously then you need to create them yourself.

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 5
    Dim f2 As New Form2

    f2.Show()
Next
```

You might like to check out [my blog post](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/07/vbnet-default-form-instances.html) on the subject of default instances to learn more.

By the way, you can also combine the two lines within that loop into one, but note that you cannot start a line with the `New` keyword, so this is one of the few times that the `Call` keyword is useful.

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 5
    Call New Form2().Show()
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create new instances.For example:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 5
        Dim frm As New Form2
        frm.Show()
Next
```

In case you need to access those instances you can keep them in a List

```
Dim forms As New List(Of Form)(5)
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For i As Integer = 1 To forms.Capacity
        Dim frm As New frmBaleRevision
        forms.Add(frm)
        frm.Show()
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with this code and change the properties of each form (in this example it gonna be the text of the form):

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For i As Integer = 1 To 5
        Dim x As New Form2
        x.Text = "New Form " & i
        x.Show()
    Next
End Sub
```